# Is it better to upgrade Fedora 17 or install new Fedora 18?

Tags: fedora, upgrade

I have a good and configured Fedora 17, I am very happy with it. I am going to upgrade it to Fedora 18 using `FedUp`, I was wondering can i do it easily without any break or problem or it is better to install a fresh Fedora 18. I have several concerns after upgrading:

- My Fedora performance.
- Break My fedora and does not boot.
- Some of my software does not run.

I must mention that i have installed RPM fusion packages on my Fedora 17.

Please advise me if you have any knowledge or experience about this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always a good idea to perform a fresh install, but if you are concerned about saving files and settings, go ahead and use `Fedup`. Remember that Fedora is a development platform for `RHEL`, so don't expect enterprise grade stability. Crashes and incompatibilities are expected with this platform. See [How Can I Upgrade My System with FedUp?](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp#How_Can_I_Upgrade_My_System_with_FedUp.3F) for more information

Comment: before performing the upgrade, it might be a good idea to check if rpmfusion repo has already the packages for F18. Still I don't recommend just yet if you need to use the kernel-devel. The kernel that comes is 3.6.10 but the devel is still in kernel-3.6.7

Comment: I checked RPM Fusion site and it released packages for Fedora 18. Do you recommend me to remove rpm fusion fedora 17 repository before update?

Comment: @SaeedZarinfam: if you have packages from rpmfusion installed, removing the repo will probably make things worse, not better. However, you may find the upgrade goes most smoothly if you yum remove all of the rpmfusion packages before upgrade, and put them back afterwards. (Probably not necessary, but will reduce the chance of hitting an oddity.)

Answer (score 3):

I also have RPM Fusion repos and ran the upgrade with `fedup`.

The issues I noticed:

1. Some configuration files in `/etc` may need to be updated. The new configuration files are saved with a `.rpmnew` extension, so you can easily find these and deal with them on a case-by-case basis.
2. As someone else noted, KDE failed to allow me to log in. This turned out to be because Fedora 18 shipped with KDE 4.9.4 while Fedora 17 had already received KDE 4.9.5 in updates. Something like this often happens on day-one upgrades. The solution was to run `yum distro-sync` after the upgrade.
3. There were a few leftover packages with no equivalent in Fedora 18, and a few packages which didn't get installed despite the fact that they might be useful. You probably won't miss these, though again you can deal with them on a case-by-case basis if you run into this situation.
4. Google Chrome, installed from Google's yum repo, failed to run after the upgrade. It was necessary to reinstall it with `yum reinstall google-chrome-stable`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried upgrading from F17 using fedup, and afterwards KDE wouldn't load. IceWM would, but no application shortcuts were present and KDE apps wouldn't load when run from a terminal. I ended up doing a clean install

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you are happy with F17, and have enough space on your disk, why not installing a new system aside and keep ability to switch at boot to either one?

- you'll be able to share most data between both systems, and be comfortable to do your migration.
- moreover, if features and aspect of F17 is good for you, I would recommend to try CentOS 7 (which base is F19 I think), and is a long term supported release. This was my choice a few years ago.